# ANN model converge but lstm doesn't

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, regression

I'm trying to build LSTM architecture to predict sickness rate(0%-100%).

I had build ANN model and it converege with mse=0.8 which is acceptable for my case.

```py
import numpy 
numpy.random.seed(8) 
def build_dropout_model2(rate):
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=(10,), activation="relu"))    
    model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu")) 
    model.add(Dense(1)) model.summary() 
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam", metrics=["mean_squared_error"]) 
    model2 = build_dropout_model2()
    return model
```

Here is my LSTM Model:

```py
def lstm_model(): 
    model = Sequential() 
    model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(1,10), return_sequences= True))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences= True)) 
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences= False))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))   
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_errorrmetrics=['mean_squared_error'])      
    return model
Lstm=lstm_model()

 newlstmhis = lstm.fit(xtrr,ytr,epochs=1000 , validation_data=(xtstt, ytst),verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

I tried several tips like changing the optimzer, the layer node number and the dropout value without any improving and this model doesn't converge mse=12.4 . So could you guys based on your experience help me with some advice. And thank you all

Comment: In your lstm code, the return statement is part of the function, so put it in the function (use proper indentation) before the line `lstm = lstm_model` (which must be outside the function).

Comment: Also, describe the problem as well as the data used.

Comment: LoMaPh it's actually like you said the code work fine it was just a problem when l copied the text. My input is an array with dimension 4760x10 (of number of sick persons per town per age, number of consultation .....) My output or the y is the sickness rate.